# delete an entry from a table A if that entry is already present in a table B

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My question is somewhat similar to this one [SQL Delete Rows Based on Another Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783784/sql-delete-rows-based-on-another-table)

except for the fact two entries match if 4 columns match!

So, I have:

Table1:

```
Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra
f1           | int(32) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment
f2           | int(32)          | NO   |     | 0       |
f3           | int(32)          | NO   |     | 0       | 
f4           | int(32)          | NO   |     | 0       |
```

and another table with f1,f2,f3,f4 + other fields.
I want to delete any record in Table 1 which have a correspondence in Table 2 based on

```
T1.f1=T2.f1 and T1.f2=T2.f2 and T1.f3=T2.f3 and T1.f4=T2.f4
```

what's the most efficient way? I though of retrieving all T1 records in a program and then make n selects on T2, but there is an average of 5k records each time in T1 and I feel this is not the most efficient way...

**edit:**
as there are a lot of records I just made an index, on T2, on one single field (say field1 for argument's sake)

Comment: delete from t1 where exists (select 1 from t2 where ....)

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: edited: I am on an oracle dbms 11g and there is one index on one field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE T1.f1=T2.f1 AND T1.f2=T2.f2 AND T1.f3=T2.f3 AND T1.f4=T2.f4
)
```

The most efficient approach depends on your rdbms and the indexes used.

Comment: I added an edit: I am using oracle 11g and I have an index on one of the fields.

Comment: @Phate: you could create  composite indexes on all involved columns  putting the most selective column first; that is, the column with the most values.

Comment: Yes I though so, nevertheless T2 can easily reach millions of records and a compound index on 4 columns takes too much disk space (I already ran in an oracle exception telling me disk space reserved was finished).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sometimes, CTAS is good idea rather than DELETE.

Comment: @LalitKumarB:   i'm more familiar with sql-server than oracle. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: @TimSchmelter One more important thing, DELETE is a DML, which doesn't affect the high watermark. So, even if you delete all the rows, Oracle must scan all the blocks under the high water mark. This asktom link might be helpful for you https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:492636200346818072

Answer (score 3):

If there are too many rows to be deleted, then you could also do a **CTAS**, i.e. **`create table as select`**. From `12c` onwards, CTAS doesn't need **gathering statistics**.

**CTAS** would be much faster than **DELETE**.

- **Create** a new table with CTAS approach with required rows only
- Recreate the required **indexes** on this new table
- **Drop** the old table
- **Rename** new table name to old table name.

For example,

**Step 1**

```
CREATE TABLE t_new AS
SELECT t1.col1,
  t1.col2,
  t1.col3,
  t1.col4
FROM t1,
  t2
WHERE t1.col1 <> t2.col1
AND t1.col2   <> t2.col2
AND t1.col3   <> t2.col3
AND t1.col4   <> t2.col4;
```

**Step 2**

```
CREATE INDEX indx_name ON t_new(COLUMN_NAME)
```

**Step 3**

```
DROP TABLE t1 PURGE;
```

**Step 4**

```
ALTER TABLE t_new RENAME TO t1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a delete with join:

```
DELETE t1
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON T1.f1=T2.f1 
  AND T1.f2=T2.f2
  AND T1.f3=T2.f3
  AND T1.f4=T2.f4
```

Being a proper join, this syntax typically yields the best performance. An index on one (or more) of the columns in T2 will help.

Comment: To add more to the performance, if proper primary and foreign key constraints are present, then the join would have table scan only on the parent table.